# Inserting Selected Item on Specific Folder

Tags: c#, winforms, create-directory

I have 2 buttons (Button1 - Browse ; Button2 - Upload) and 1 textBox

Here is the scenario. When I click on Browse, it will open a window and will browse for a specific item.
The selected item will display on textbox.

```
private void Browse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnSample.Title = "Sample File Upload";
    btnSample.InitialDirectory = @"c:\";
    btnSample.Filter = "TIF|*.tif|JPG|*.jpg|GIF|*.gif|PNG|*.png|BMP|*.bmp|PDF|*.pdf|XLS|*.xls|DOC|*.doc|XLSX|*.xlsx|DOCX|*.docx";
    btnSample.FilterIndex = 2;
    btnSample.RestoreDirectory = true;
    if (btnSample.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        textBox1.Text = btnSample.FileName;
    }
}
```

When I click on the Upload Button the file on the textbox will be on the created folder.
I'm done with creating the folder. but my problem is how can i insert the selected file on the folder.

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string path = @"C:\SampleFolder\NewFolder";
    if (!Directory.Exists(path))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
        MessageBox.Show("Successfully Created New Directory");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Filename Exist");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var sourceFilePath = @"C:\temp\file.txt";
var destFilePath= @"C:\otherFolder\file.txt";
```

If you want to [move](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move.aspx) the file:

```
File.Move(sourceFilePath, destFilePath);
```

If you want to [copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.file.copy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) the file

```
File.Copy(sourceFilePath, destFilePath);
```

easy huh?
ofcourse, you'd have to adapt the paths to your problem...